# Counting grouped outcomes into separate columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have row-per-player row-per-outcome row-per-trial data similar to this:

```
    player  coin
0    Alice heads
1    Alice tails
2    Alice heads
3    Alice tails
4    Alice tails
5      Bob heads
6      Bob heads
7      Bob heads
8      Bob tails
9      Bob heads
```

I want row-per-player **column**-per-outcome **count** data:

```
    player heads tails
0    Alice     2     3
1      Bob     4     1
```

What is the simplest way to perform this transformation using pandas?

It's possible to do it by grouping by (player, coin), getting the size of each group, filtering the heads data and tails data into separate data frames, then outer joining those dataframes. But that ends up being quite verbose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html)

```
pd.crosstab(df.player, df.coin)
```

---

```
coin    heads  tails
player              
Alice       2      3
Bob         4      1
```

Comment: Well. I checked it and it works. That ends up being *way* simpler than I was even hoping for.